# RxJs : How to close subscription of nested observable.subscribe call

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Within my Angular app :

i ve this treatment :

```
mySubjectOne = new Subject();

methodOne(){
    this.subscriptionOne = mySubjectOne.subscribe((response) => {
      this.methodTwo();
    })
}

methodTwo(){
  this.subscriptionTwo = return this.httpClient.post(myurl , mydata).subscribe((response) => {
      myTreatment(); // MY TREATMENT
  })
}
```

My probleme is whenever "**mySubjectOne** " is called methodOne calls **methodTwo** ,

and the subscriptionTwo  seems to **be cloned to be +1** every time :

for  example in the third time of calling : methodOne , it seems that there were 4 subscriptionTwo  invoqued

How may i close the subsrciption subscriptionTwo  just after TREATMENT and let it be recreated in each rime

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: why don't you use `forkjoin` for the same, In `forkjoin` will return `observer` after all the request is completed.

Comment: @YashRami, I believe that this is not gonna work, cause `forkjoin` will emit when all the observables are completed.

Comment: yeah true if your API call does not depend on first api call then you can use `forkjoin` for the same. and in this case it is not depend on first API call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) to achieve exactly this behavior.
Note that there are also other operators such as `exhaustMap` or `mergeMap` that may fit your desired behavior even more. Read up on the source provided.

```
mySubjectOne = new Subject();

methodOne() {
  this.subscriptionOne = mySubjectOne.pipe(
    switchMap((response) => this.methodTwo()),
  )
    .subscribe((response) => {
      myTreatment();
  });
}

methodTwo() {
  this.subscriptionTwo = return this.httpClient.post(myurl , mydata);
}
```

Now whenever `mySubjectOne` fires, `methodTwo` will be executed. Once that's done, `myTreatment` will run.

Note that you should run `methodOne` just once (to initialize the subscription), as otherwise the subscription may run multiple times.
So I suggest to move the initialization process into your constructor or maybe `ngOnInit`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is a bad idea to subscribe inside a subscription. 
You better use [SwitchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) to handle it.

If you prefer to go your way, you could use [TakeUntil](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takeuntil) to emit the end of your subscription.